# How can I repeat calling a function until it returns None?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, language-extension

Suppose I have 2 functions

`Func<Id, Option<Employee>> FindEmployee`

It returns an employee if the Id is found, otherwise `None`;

`Func<Employee, Option<Entry>> PromptPassword`

It will open a dialog asking for password, if OK button is hit, it will return the user entry; if cancel is hit, it will return None

I would like to have an elegant way to composite these 2 functions, basically I want to do:

```
FindEmployee.Map(emp => 
  {
     while (true)
     {
         var result = PromptPassword (emp);
         if (result.IsNone)
         {
             return false;
         }

         bool matched = result.Where(a => a.EntryContent == emp.Password)
                              .Some(r => true)
                              .None(false);
         if (matched)
             return true;
      }
  });
```

The end result is an Option 
You see, I want to keep prompting for password until the user enter it correctly. But using a while loop inside a `Map` is so ugly.

It must have a better way to write this. can anyone give a hint?

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, which Option<T> is this? Is it from F# or some other library?

Comment: Also, why does PromptPassword receive an Employee? Why, if the password verification happens later in the line starting `bool matches = ...`.
And a `while(true){...}` will keep iterating forever. I mean, your snippet of code is wrong, reglardless of its elegance. It just won't work.
You need to edit your question so that at least your snippet of code makes sense.

Comment: @caeus Possibly some value in `emp` is used in the prompt dialog. And a `while` loop will not iterate forever if the code `return`s. I see no reason to believe that OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: @JLRishe, you're right about the return. It will make it end. What's the type of "emp"? Employee or Option<Employee>?

Comment: @caeus Given that OP is accessing `emp.Password`, I'd imagine it's `Employee`.

Comment: So then what is the type signature of that `.Map` method? It's super confusing. Looks like it's a method to compose functions, but if that were the case, the type of emp, should be Option<Employee>

Comment: @caeus Monadic map methods provide a way to operate on the monad's underlying type. So I'd imagine that `Option<Employee>.Map()` takes a `Func<Employee, T>` as its argument and returns an `Option<T>` (in this case, `T` would be `bool`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164684/discussion-between-caeus-and-jlrishe).

Comment: @caeus C# has Map, I am using language-ext, which is an extension on top of Linq, so it has Map, Bind, Option, Either, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In F# I would probably express your algorithm like this:

```
findEmployee |> Option.map (fun emp ->
    let rec loop () =
        match PromptPassword emp with
        | None -> false
        | Some a -> a.EntryContent = emp.Password || loop ()
    loop ())
```

The equivalent in C# would probably look as follows:

```
FindEmployee.Map(emp =>
    {
        do {
            var result = PromptPassword(emp);
            if (result.IsNone) return false;
        } while (result.Where(a => a.EntryContent == emp.Password).IsNone);
        return true;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

define a function like this

```
bool Insist(Employee:emp){
  var result = PromptPassword (emp);
  if (result.IsNone)
  {
     return false;
  }

  bool matched = result.Where(a => a.EntryContent == emp.Password)
                              .Some(r => true)
                              .None(false);
  if(matched)
  {
     return true;
  }else
  {
     return Insist(emp);
  }

}
```

Then you can just go and

```
FindEmployee(id).Map(emp => 
  {
     return Insist(emp);
  });
```

Comment: I reckon you could change the second part to `FindEmployee.Map(Insist)`. Not sure if this is much of an improvement though. I think OP is looking for a pre-established pattern for doing this kind of thing in FP/Rx.

Comment: Well, I'm not really sure if that's possible in C#. As he's asking for FP advice, nothing more FP that good ol' recursion. Haha

Comment: I actually do feel I should just write an additional method using the pass-in function. thanks for the reply

Answer (score -5):

You could make use of the goto statement right? and then get rid of the while loop...

Comment: Is this a joke?

Comment: OP is asking about a _better_ and more elegant way to accomplish what they're doing. I think most people would agree that `goto` would not be better than what they have.